# Via Windows command line, how can we compile a Netbeans C/C++ application?

Tags: c++, netbeans, command-line, ant, compilation

Let's take this [simple C/C++ application Netbeans project folder](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6194904/2015.Q3/CppApplication_1.zip).

In Netbeans IDE, we just hit build button on the toolbar to build the application.

I want to do that automatically via Windows command line, how can I do that?

I did google, and found some related posts though not very helpful for me except telling me to call `ant dist` - though I don't have the `build.xml` in my Netbeans 8 project.

p.s. I have hundreds of student submissions and need to verify which one is compilable. 
I also post on Netbeans forum [here](http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?t=63763&start=0&postdays=0&postorder=asc&highlight=).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to do that automatically via Windows command line, how can I do that?

NetBeans uses Makefile-based projects as default for C/C++ projects, so you can use `make` to build your project:

```
cd <Project dir>
make
```

It's also possible to build other make-targets (eg. `make all` or `make test` (builds / runs tests)).

---

**Note:** The Cygwin bin dir (`CYGWIN_HOME\bin`) must be in system `PATH` - same applies to other environments (MinGW, Gcc etc).

Comment: I have to add CYGWIN_HOME\bin to system PATH - please update your answer to reflect this and get accepted. Thank you!